# Guice vs EJB for pooling on injections

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, guice

what is the comparison between EJB pooling and Guice? Can Guice be a alternative for EJB?

In EJB Session beans will be allocated from pool to have rapid instancing but what about Guice?

RGDS

Answer (score 3):

I believe that nop, Guice cannot fully replace EJB.

Guice only implements [JSR-330](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330), CDI implements both [JSR-330](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) and [JSR-299](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299).

EJB is another thing.

You can use CDI to inject EJBs. Not sure, but I trully believe that it will not work with Guice, because of JSR-299.

Comment: sure, but what about pool-instancing? is there any pooling like ejb?

Comment: like EJB, nope. EJB use CDI (sorry, my first answer was wrong, I mistake the names), CDI provides "Context and DI for Java EE", Guice is just a lighweith DI container.